# How to make my mouse go faster?

Tags: mouse, cursor, mouse-cursor

I had an old Omega mouse. A really cheap one and it got broken. Now I bought an Elephant 2000 DPI mouse and it is going really really slow. Almost half the speed of my other mouse. I checked control_panel for mouse options and my pointer options is set to max. How can I get my mouse to go faster ?

Answer (score 1):

In the windows `control panel`, `mouse`, you have a tab called `Cursor options` (translated)

There is a checkbox called `Enhance precision of the mouse cursor`. Disable this, then click apply.

Answer (score 0):

The model of the mouse you have specified looks unfamiliar, and I could not find any info about it on the net. But normally windows settings are more then enough for basic usage. For anything beyond basic usage or for more complex hardware you always need to install OEM's drivers + software and use custom settings provided by software. This applies to most high-DPI mice.

Try downloading software from OEM's website (or installing from CD if you got one with you mouse) - and look for sensitivity settings within the software rather then windows standard settings.

Good luck